# Question on for-loop, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Am basically new to Objective-C. This is the question that i have.
How to i send in individual characters of string into a for-loop and output each of those characters in the for-loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *input = @"input string";

for ( NSInteger i=0; i<[input length]; i++ )
{
    unichar c = [input characterAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Character at %d: %c == %04x == %d",i,c,(int)c,(int)c);
}
```

Comment: Wow that was superfast. So, in the for-loop, how do we print the ascii values of those characters instead of printing the characters themselves?

Comment: See the updated answer. Since obj-c knows the `unichar` type, we have to be prepared that it's two bytes long.

Comment: Note that in a GUI app, this will block the event loop. Your app's interface won't be redrawn to show any updates until the for() is finished, and if it blocks for *too* long, you'll get a spinning technicolor pizza of death.

Comment: I have converted these characters into ascii and xored them with a predefined value and then got the output. I have tried to put these values into a array and then print it out. but there was an error. this is the code :

Comment: int ascii = (char)z;
  
  
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:ascii]; 
  

NSLog(@"The content of arry is : %@",array);

Comment: This should be a new question rather thaan a comment here. But the problem in your code is that an `int` is not an object. You can wrap it in an object using `[NSNumber numberWithInt:ascii]`